# Как сделать правильно progressbar в tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Всем доброго времени суток) Как правильно написать код чтобы с каждым выводом і изменялся progressbar?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = Tk()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=100)
pb.pack()

for i in range(11):
    print(i)
    pb.step(10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В режиме [`mode='determinate'`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Progressbar.html), `ttk.Progressbar` меняется в зависимости от `pb['value']`

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time, threading
root = Tk()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode="determinate")
pb.pack()

def progress():
    for i in range(11):
        pb['value'] += i
        time.sleep(.3)

threading.Thread(target=progress).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Только tkinter не потокобезопасная библиотека - если в ещё одном потоке что то делает другой виджет, могут быть забавные или не очень забавные побочные эффекты, появление которых зависит от версии интера,версии и типа ОС, фаз луны и прочего.

Варианты в данном случае:

1. объединить полезное действие с обновлением бара
2. использовать yeld
3. уйти на PyQt